Workflow changes from the forked repo will be triggered in the source repo actions
Is the below statement true ?
When you create an action in a pull request from a forked repository, the workflow from the base repository (the master or main branch) is used to run the actions. This ensures that only the trusted workflows defined in the base repository are executed, maintaining security and consistency.

A new workflow in a forked repo will not run until it is merged to the default branch.
A modified existing workflow will be able to run but only after a manual approval by someone who has write permissions to the base repo.
Even when it runs, it will be issued a token with limited permissions - it will not be able to modify base repo, e.g. push tags (needs base repo setting) and it will not be able to use base repo secrets.
